# R plumber api works in console, but not with systemd

Tags: r, systemd, plumber

I have a weather station that sends data out periodically and want to make an API with plumber to receive and save the JSON data. My script is

```
# plumber.R
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#' @post /station
#' @serializer json
#' @param wind_direction_raw
#' @param rain_amount_raw
#' @param timestamp
#' @param elapsed_time
#' @param wind_speed_raw
#' @param message_id
function(req, wind_direction_raw, rain_amount_raw, timestamp,
    elapsed_time, wind_speed_raw, message_id){

    new_data <- tibble("wind_direction_raw" = wind_direction_raw, 
        "rain_amount_raw" = rain_amount_raw,
        "wind_speed_raw" = wind_speed_raw,
        "timestamp" = ymd_hms(paste(timestamp[1:6], collapse="="), tz = "UTC"), 
        "elapsed_time" = elapsed_time, 
        "message_id" = message_id)

    write_path <- paste0("/home/pi/weather_station/data/weather_data_", 
            Sys.Date(), ".csv")

    readr::write_csv(new_data, write_path, append=TRUE)
```

When I open an `R` session and type

```
> library(plumber)
> weather_service <- pr('/home/pi/weather_station/weather_api/receive_json.R')
> pr_run(weather_service, port=9494, host='192.168.1.151')
```

and then on another computer send some json with `curl` with

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"elapsed_time": 6245, "timestamp": "[2020, 7, 26, 12, 2, 21, 6, 208]", "wind_direction_raw": 108, "wind_speed_raw": 5, "message_id": 666, "rain_amount_raw": "0"}' http://192.168.1.151:9494/station
```

it works fine. Same with my actual weather station.

However when I use this systemd service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Plumber API

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/Rscript -e "library(plumber); pr_run(pr('/home/pi/weather_station/weather_api/receive_json.R'), port=9494, host='192.168.1.151')"
Restart= always
RestartSec=60
SyslogIdentifier=WeatherAPI

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Neither the weather station or my `curl` example can send data. It seems to hang in the middle of the send process, since the `curl` process hangs and never finishes.

`sudo systemctl status` looks good with

```
Feb 03 17:24:25 gatesPi4 systemd[1]: Started Plumber API.
Feb 03 17:24:29 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.0 ──
Feb 03 17:24:29 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ✔ ggplot2 3.3.2     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
Feb 03 17:24:29 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ✔ tibble  3.0.1     ✔ dplyr   1.0.0
Feb 03 17:24:29 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ✔ tidyr   1.1.0     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
Feb 03 17:24:29 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ✔ readr   1.3.1     ✔ forcats 0.5.0
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ✖ tidyr::extract()   masks magrittr::extract()
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ✖ dplyr::filter()    masks stats::filter()
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ✖ dplyr::lag()       masks stats::lag()
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: ✖ purrr::set_names() masks magrittr::set_names()
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: Attaching package: ‘lubridate’
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]:     date, intersect, setdiff, union
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: Running plumber API at http://192.168.1.151:9494
Feb 03 17:24:30 gatesPi4 WeatherAPI[14465]: Running swagger Docs at http://192.168.1.151:9494/__docs__/
```

Any ideas? I tried adding `Users=pi` to the service file, to run as a user and not root, but no change in behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe check systemctl status to see if your service comes alive.

Comment: @pgcudahy - can you provide the OS and version details?

Comment: My gut feel is that the reason the service is not working is that the service cannot find the interface after reboot. The interface may be renamed. I reserve the right to be wrong but hopefully, that will point you in the right direction. Stay safe and well.

Comment: Maybe it's completely off, but might it be a permission issue? I see that you write stuff on the filesystem; are you sure that the user who execute it has the correct permissions? You maybe want to try something that does not involve any read/write from files (for instances just returning the input) to see whether it works.

Comment: This is on raspbian buster on a raspberry pi 4. @nicola I do worry about permissions errors, but systemd daemons run as root so not sure how that could be it. I've also tried creating the files with absolute maximum permissions (anyone can r/w/x) with no improvement